# How to add a message of amount of settings

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, lua, lua-api

well I have a question, I was wondering if it is possible to count the settings that exist within a function lua_getglobal.

I have a file called define.lua he is as follows:

```
tbl {
     macro_enable = true;
     macro_value = 100;
     time_expire = 60;
     enable_mac = true;
};
```

What I'm trying to insert a message in my code to count the amount of existetes settings

code:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "tbl");

lua_getfield(L, -1, "macro_enable");
p->macro_enable = lua_toboolean(L, -1);

lua_getfield(L, -1, "macro_value");
p->macro_value = lua_tointeger(L, -1);

lua_getfield(L, -1, "time_expire");
p->time_expire = lua_tointeger(L, -1);

lua_getfield(L, -1, "enable_mac");
p->enable_mac = lua_toboolean(L, -1);
```

Want to add a message.

```
printf ("% d configurations have been read");
```

I tried to do a loop more without success

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a loop then start with

```
Int count=0;
```

And on each line you read a config field:

```
Count+=1;
```

Your printf statement should say:

```
printf ("% d configurations have been read",count);
```

Comment: wanted to use loop to avoid extra code, however the following error occurs: `PANIC: unprotected erro in call to lua API (attempt to index a bollean value)`